# Simple command-line program for Linux that scedules file/directory deletion, allowing undo it within a minute

Tags: linux, file-management, command-line

I want a simple little open source program/script that does this:

1. Invoked with a file or directory
2. Immediately renames away the specified files (e.g. into .hidden .files)
3. Waits in background for N minutes, then actually `rm -Rf`s the files
4. Has easy way to cancel the pending deletion.

Out of sight - out of mind; but I can reconsider. And no piles of old files in uncleared for ages "trash can".

Comment: I can't think of any terminal software that does this now, though most GUI file managers do, that's what you want to duplicate in a terminal? You could move the files to a trash folder first, an alias for `rm -Rf` maybe. Then erase the trash folder every hour or so with a cron job... or a custom process/bash script that erases the trash after N minutes of inactivity. Maybe "borrowing" your GUI file manager's trash folder & moving files there might work.

Comment: I don't want to copy the files from tmpfs to hard drive just to remove them. Actually I expect the program to rename the file in place and stay in memory for a while.

Comment: You can move files in tmpfs too, and mkdir a trash. But I'd imagine there is an existing program for this already, someone must have thought it would be useful sometime in the last 30+ years of shell / terminal programming... searched debian / suse / fedora repos? I didn't spot anything immediately in [Ubuntu's repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bash+trash+undo+delete&searchon=all), but [autotrash](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/autotrash) might be useful

Comment: @Xen2050 ever heard about the `at` command? Your idea of an alias (or shell script) sounds good. Instead of setting up Cron jobs you could utilize `at` (pseudo-code: `at +06:00 rm -rf $1` to delete the entire directory after 6h). `at` should be available with all Linux distris. On Debian e.g. via `sudo apt install at`.

Comment: @Izzy, 1. `at +00:01 echo qqq` -> `syntax error. Last token seen: +   Garbled time`; 2. How do I cancel such deletion reliably?

Comment: @Vi. by removing the `at` job (`atrm`, `atq` to list the queue AFAIK). I've never directly worked with `at`, so I'm not sure about the syntax – what I wrote above is "pseudo-code" abstracted from its use in a Perl module (I use FHEM, which integrates `at` for scheduling). For details and examples, see e.g. at our sister site: [Why do we need the “at” command in Linux?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/97882/209279), plus [Linux at, batch, atq, and atrm commands](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) (nice little tutorial). So it's rather `at -f myscript.sh now +6 hours`.

Comment: btrfs has a snapshot feature which automatically snapshots changes.  You could probably cron a delete process or something.  This would, of course, require you to change filesystem which is a bother.

Comment: btrfs snapshotting typically requires root